# Subtracting from a SUM range by the number of positive entries returned?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

So I have a Formula like this:

=SUM(SUMIF(A1:A10,">0")-B1)

But I want to subtract the value of B1 multiplied by the number of positive returns from the A1:A10 range.

For example, if only 3 entry's  in the rage are valid, I minus by B1 three times.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go:

```
=SUM(SUMIF(A1:A10,">0")-B1*COUNTIF(A1:A10,">0"))
```

Use `COUNTIF` to count the number of values greater than 0 in the range A1:A10 and then multiply that by B1.